# Getting HTTP 401 Unauthorized response from SOAP call using php-ews trying to connect to Exchange server

Tags: exchange-server, ntlm, http-status-code-401, php-ews

I am using the latest version (1.0.0-beta-4) of James I. Armes php-ews code (https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews) to connect to a local Exchange serge (Exchange 2010 SP1).  This code connects just fine to Office/365, but it is getting ah 'HTTP 401 Unauthorized' back when it tries to connect to our local Exchange server.  I have seen some old entries addressing similar problems, but none with a specific answer.  Any suggestions on where to look?

Comment: Are you sure Exchange 2010 supports the same SOAP interface?

Comment: Yes, we have other code talking to this Exchange server over SOAP.  It may have something to do with specific versions of curl and/or ntlm?

Answer (score 2):

I remember encountering something similar, where the server that I was using threw a 401 if you the SOAP client was trying to send a combination of `CURLAUTH_BASIC` and `CURLAUTH_NTLM`. I remember the solution was to try and find the [`SoapClient`](https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ntlm/blob/master/src/SoapClient.php) file and changing the `CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH` [option](https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ntlm/blob/master/src/SoapClient.php#L189) to either `CURLAUTH_BASIC`, `CURLAUTH_BASIC | CURLAUTH_NTLM` or `CURLAUTH_NTLM` until you found the setting that worked for you.

On a side note, I'd recommend you trying my alternative library, [`garethp/php-ews`](https://github.com/Garethp/php-ews), as it provides many benefits (including simpler ways to use EWS) and I try to provide support for people on the issues page